# $\bigcap\limits_{\varphi\in E^*}\ker(\varphi)$ and the Axiom of Choise

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

**Context.**

Give a nonzero $K$-vector space $E$, it is known that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{\varphi\in E^*}\ker(\varphi)=0$ under AC.

It is also known that, without AC, there are models of ZF in which some non zero vector space do not have nonzero linear forms. For such an $E$, $\displaystyle \bigcap_{\varphi\in E^*}\ker(\varphi)=E.$

So my question is:

**Question.** Are there models of ZF for which the dimension of $\displaystyle \bigcap_{\varphi\in E^*}\ker(\varphi)$ can have any prescribed cardinality $\kappa$? (the model may depend on $\kappa$, even if it would be supernice to have a single model which works for any cardinality).

Or, do we have necessarily the alternative  $\displaystyle \bigcap_{\varphi\in E^*}\ker(\varphi)=0$ or $E$?

I am also interested in the weaker question: can $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\varphi\in E^*}\ker(\varphi)$ be a nonzero proper subspace of $E$?

**Side remark.** There is no precise reason why I am interested in this, just plain curiosity. These questions popped out because I realized that I needed the existence of some  complement of a given line of $E$ to prove that the intersection above is zero.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you know of any result about the action of linear automorphisms on $E\setminus \{0\}$ without AC? For instance, if $\mathrm{Aut}(E)$ acts transitively on $P(E)$ and there is a nonzero linear form, then one can conclude that $\bigcap_{\varphi} \ker \varphi = 0$

Comment: What is a "linear form"? Are we talking about topological spaces or just arbitrary vector spaces?

Comment: Just a linear map from $E$ to $K$, where $E$ is an arbitrary vector space over an arbitrary field $K$

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather boring/trivial answer to an interesting question. Maybe it can help you reformulate your question to one that admits a more interesting answer!

Let $E$ be a vector space with no non-zero linear form. Now consider the vector space $V=E\oplus K$. The linear form $\varphi(e,c)=c$ has kernel $E$, and conversely any linear form $\psi$ on $V$ restricts to a linear form on $E$, which must be zero, so $E\subseteq \ker(\psi)$. Thus $\bigcap_{\varphi\in V^*} \ker(\varphi)=E$.

More generally, for any set $I$, if we set $V=E\oplus \bigoplus_{i\in I} K$, we have $\bigcap_{\varphi\in V^*} \ker(\varphi)=E$.

This answers your second question, showing that the intersection of the kernels of linear forms can be a proper (and in fact a relatively small) subspace of $V$. For the first, you ask about the dimension of this subspace. I don't think this makes sense: any vector space with a basis has non-zero linear forms. In the absence of a basis, it's not clear what "dimension" means.

Comment: Do you have an example of a vector space with no non-zero linear forms? 

About dimension, in the absence of AC we can't prove that there is a basis. So, indeed, we can't really talk about dimension. From your comment, I understand a vector space without non-zero linear form also is a result of not having AC. Is that so?

Comment: @ugurefem See the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: @ugurefem ...  My favorite example is the Banach space $Y = l^\infty/c_0$.  It cannot be proved in ZF that $Y$ has a nonzero linear functional.